# Maximum App ID limit has been reached

Tags: ios, xcode

Получается, когда указываю свой ID в General/Identity/Team чтобы отладить на устройстве.

Теперь, я так понял, не смогу запускать с этим профилем? А как создавать новые профили?

[image: Maximum App ID limit has been reached]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам вывелось сообщение, что лимит на запуски свеженаписанных приложений = 10, на каждые 7 дней. То есть, семь дней спустя вы снова сможете запустить до 10 различных приложений. 
Если вам этого мало, вы можете создать другой аккаунт разработчика. ([cсылка](https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=create))